# DocuSign does not send emails after first recipient when using signing order

Tags: docusignapi, docusign-sdk

I am using DocuSign via the API in Java as develop with signing order. The first receipient receives an email and signs and everything works fine.
Now the second receipient should receive an e-mail but unfortunately not. Even when the status of the second receipient changed from created to sent (via API and on DocuSing-Profile).

I also see the changes in the manage profile, the status there works fine and changed from created to sent but the receipient does not receive any e-mail.

It looks like, docusign does not send any email after first receipient when using the signing order. Have anyone ever experienced this bug? any Idea?

PS: I also tried the following:

- no siging order -> all receipients receive the email (including email of second receipient).
- changing the order: the second receipient become the first one and vice versa -> the first receives the e-mail normally, the second not -> that means that the e-mails receive with no problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the **clientUserId** attribute for the second signer in your API call? Of so, then you set him or her to be an embedded signer. They don't get email notifications to sign since they sign via your app.

Also check your envelope via the DocuSign web app. Check that the signe's information (including email address) is correct.

And check with the second signer. Email could be in their notifications, low priority, or spam folders.

Still having problems? Update your question to include the DocuSign api call log (remove any private info first)

Comment: Setting the **clientUserId** to **null** solved the problem. The user is now getting the email. Thanks